# how to get original index of tableview when search is perform in searchbar?

Tags: ios, iphone, searchbar

I am working on project in which data come from server.

Data contain(Latitude,Longitude,District and Street Name). I saved each field in separate array and just display district and street name related to that location on tableview.

When user click on specific row of table-view another screen appears and location of that specific index of tableviewcell shows on map viva specific lat,lon.

When I implement search bar on tableview to search district name then how can I get exact longitude and latitude for searched district?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get index of district from district array and get longitude from longitude array at same index.

Swift:

```
let index = find(district,districtArray)!
let longitude = longitudeArray[index]
let latitude = latitudeArray[index]
```

Objective-C:

```
int index = [districtArray indexOfObject:district];
double latitude = latitudeArray[index];
double longitude = longitudeArray[index];
```

I assume that in all arrays data exists, but if there's a chance that some array at some index will be empty do error checking as well.

Comment: I have three arrays,all three are 20 elements and element at index 0 have relevent data in another array at same index.the problem is that,when i perform search viva searchbar on one array,then how i get relevant data from other two arrays. For example,i have district array and other two are latitude and longitude array.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) Search_TF_Call {
    txtForSearch.placeholder=@"Type a name";
    txtForSearch.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    txtForSearch.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    [txtForSearch addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}

- (void) textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)txtFld {
    NSMutableArray *nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:tempContact];
    NSString *match = txtFld.text;
    NSMutableArray *listFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc]  init];
    NSArray *terms = [match componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet nonBaseCharacterSet]];

    for (NSString *term in terms) {
        if([term length] == 0) { continue; }

        NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", term];
        [listFiles addObject:p];
    }

    NSPredicate *filter = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:listFiles];
    listFiles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[nameArray  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter]];
    if (txtFld.text.length > 0) {
        sortedArrayForTempContact = listFiles;
    }
    else {
        sortedArrayForTempContact = tempContact;
    }
    [tblView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: nameArray and sortedArrayForTempContact declare in .h file

Comment: I have three arrays,all three are 20 elements and element at index 0 have relevent data in another array at same index.the problem is that,when i perform search viva searchbar on one array,then how i get relevant data from other two arrays. For example,i have district array and other two are latitude and longitude array.